# How to guarantee a row if the query returns no rows?

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I have the following union query:

```
select dataItem,1 as sortOrder from table1
union
select dataItem,2 from table2
order by sortOrder
```

If the first `select` query returns one row and the second `select` query returns no rows, then I get the following result:

```
dataItem | sortOrder
---------+----------
12345    | 1
```

I would like to make sure that there is always at least one row, so that if the seconde query returns no rows, we would have:

```
dataItem | sortOrder
---------+----------
12345    | 1
0        | 2
```

How can I make this happen?

Comment: Create a function which will return rowtype and inside this function check if there is no rows , create a new one and return it

Answer (score 2):

The idea is to add union of max(dataItem) or 0 . Not sure on ACCESS syntax

```
select dataItem,1 as sortOrder from table1
union
select dataItem, 2 from table2
union 
select iif(max(dataItem) is null, 0, max(dataItem)), 2 from table2
order by sortOrder
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add one more `union` and this `query` checks `if there is any row in table2`, if `no rows` then `return row with default values`

```
select dataItem,1 as sortOrder from table1
union
select dataItem,2 from table2    
union
select 0,2
where not exists (select 1 from table2)
order by sortOrder
```

Comment: Whilst this code snippet is welcome, and may provide some help, it would be [greatly improved if it included an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of *how* and *why* this solves the problem. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now!  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.